# Primefaces Data table row id

Tags: html, jsf, datatable, primefaces

How can I **set** id (HTML attribute) to DataTable row (tr element) in Primefaces ?
I searched, but everywhere is how get id.
I need this because I want integrate pf data table with [rowReordering plugin](http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the id of the `<tr>` elements in the Primefaces data table from the PrimeFaces API, but it doesn't appear as if it requires the rows themselves to have a specific id, so it is possible to do this from Javascript at the client side after a postback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ui-datatable-data').children().each(function(index, element) {
    element.attr('id', 'foo_' + index);
  };
};
```

This will find every tbody element for jQuery and Primefaces datatables and set the id of the `tr` children to a unique and predictable id.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried [maple_shaft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650425/maple-shaft)'s answer and got a few issues. I fixed the issues and here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.ui-datatable-data').children().each(function (index, element) {
      element.setAttribute('id', 'row_' + index);
   });
});
```

Now each of my rows has its own ID as 'id="row0"'

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this? PF has row-ordering built-in